# Interactive animation of 3d model on user touch

Tags: android, animation, model, unity-game-engine, interactive

I am new to Unity3d and I'm developing an AR app for Android, using [NyARToolkit](https://www.artoolworks.com/products/desktop/nyartoolkit) plugin. I need some guidance to accomplice the following effect.

Lets assume, there is a 3d model as a GameObject, depicting a building floor with a starting point namely "You Are Here". I want to animate the route from the starting point to other points on this level, on user choice, if a certain room get touched.

The following images shows the idea of this concept:

[image]

[image]

I have look for something similar on S.O., but could not find something matching my needs, so
am in need of your help to give me some advice on how to implement this function in Unity3d. I though of using e.g. a java script, with var values storing the x,y of the point on screen?

Because I am newbie your point of view, on the feasibility of this concept is vital to give me the right way of doing this in Unity3d.

Thank all for your time reading, waiting for your reply. In case you want me to elaborate more on this concept, I' ll be willing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to overlay a rect or a plane on each clickable object, and dynamically change the overlaid plane's visibility:

```
void ToogleVisibility(GameObject plane, bool bEnable)
{
    plane.setActive(bEnable);
}
```

[image]  [image]

Edit: I think it is already very clear, but it seems not the case for the OP. See below the full code.

```
public class Highlight : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject room1=null;
GameObject room2=null;

bool bRoom1Active = false;
bool bRoom2Active =false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    room1 = GameObject.Find ("Room1");
    room2 = GameObject.Find ("Room2");
    room1.SetActive (false);
    room2.SetActive (false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnGUI()  //Substitute this with your OnTouch() logic
{

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 30), "Toggle Room1")) {
        bRoom1Active = !bRoom1Active;
        room1.SetActive(bRoom1Active);
    }
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 60, 100, 30), "Toggle Room2")) {
        bRoom2Active = !bRoom2Active;
        room2.SetActive(bRoom2Active);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you @David, for your answer. Afterwards, I should add a script to be run on those planes or rects? Please elaborate more on these suggestion of yours, cause I don't fully follow your though.